# Fill with zero to complete a defined number in sql

Tags: sql, oracle

I need to complete cards numbers in sql. I have the prefix =11111 and the number of the card which is variable, therefore it could be '25' or '2130' but at the end I must have 14 numbers. So I need to fill spaces with zeros.
I've read about 'LPAD' but I don't understand very well this method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use lpad, but if you're starting with a number you could use a 9-digit format model instead, and concatenate that onto your prefix:

```
select '11111' || to_char(25, 'FM000000000') from dual;

11111000000025
```

The FM format modifier stops Oracle adding a space for a potential +/- sign indicator.

[SQL Fiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/9eecb7/2918)

Answer (score 0):

Use the [`ZEROFILL`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/numeric-type-attributes.html) attribute.
But your database should only be responsible for saving data and not changing it before saving.
The best way would be to send the zerofilled data to the database server.

Comment: That's for MySQL, not Oracle RDBMS.